# When using filter the question are not ordered correctly

Tags: support, tags, unanswered-questions, questions-filter

I just answered a question asked in 2013. I used a filter to filter out a certain tag and then the unanswered questions. So I took the first in the list thinking it is a recent question.

Why not sort by date desc when filtering for unanswered tags?

Comment: It sorts by vote then date

Comment: is it possible to choose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Why not sort by date desc when filtering for unanswered tags?

The current interface sorts by vote then date.

> Is it possible to choose?

There is a new navigation being tested at the moment https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate but the test version is not available on SuperUser.

The new navigation will you to sort unanswered questions aka needs answer by:

- active,
- newest, or
- votes

Here is a screenshot showing the new test interface on StackOverflow

[image]